# Find and replace variables containing non-escaped characters with sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I can use this, to find all instances of "fly" and replace it with "insect" in my file:

```
sed -i 's/fly/insect/g' ./animals.txt
```

How can I find a BASH variable and replace it with another BASH variable? E.g.:

```
name=$(echo "fly")
category=$(echo "insect")
sed -i 's/$name/$category/g' ./animals.txt
```

Update:

I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1. When I try the solutions below, it reports this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 73: unknown option to `s'
```

Update:

I discovered why the error is coming up. `$category` frequently contains lots of symbols (e.g. "/", "$", "@", "!", brackets, etc.).

```
ame=$(echo "fly")
category=$(echo "in/sect")
sed -i "s/$name/$category/g" ./animals.txt
```

The above code will create the same error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
```

Is there a way to let `sed` complete the replaces, even when it encounters these symbols?

Comment: Why `name=$(echo "fly")` and not just `name=fly`? Or `name="because it has spaces"`?

Comment: I've attempted to provide a simple example, because it is too difficult to explain all of the others. The simple example has the same problems as my full code, which is: `name=$(echo $entry | awk -F ",*" '{print $3}')` and `category=$(echo "\mymacro{"$name"}{"$description"}{"$details"}")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using double quotes

Use double quotes to make the shell expand variables while keeping whitespace:

```
sed -i "s/$name/$category/g" ./animals.txt
```

**Note:** if you need to put backslashes in your replacement (e.g. for back references), you need double slashes (\& contains the pattern match):

#### Using single quotes

If you've a lot shell meta-characters, you can do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/'$pattern'/'$category'/g' ./animals.txt
```

---

> I discovered why the error is coming up. $category frequently contains lots of symbols (e.g. "/", "$", "@", "!", brackets, etc.).

If the substitution or replacement portion contains characters like `/` then we can use different sets of `sed` delimiters. You can use something like - `@ % , ; : | _` etc. any character that does not happen to occur in your substitution and replacement.

Comment: With both methods, it prints this error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unknown option to `s'".

Comment: Looks like you are using BSD (Mac) version of `sed`. Put a quotes next to `-i` option. e.g `sed -i'' 's/...` If you are using solaris box then `-i` option won't work. Solaris sed does not support it.

Comment: Or if on mac give a backup file name. `sed -ibak 's/...`

Comment: I have GNU sed version 4.2.1 on Linux.

Comment: I am not too sure, I tested them both on GNU-SED and they work fine. Are you getting errors with other answers too?

Comment: @Village Does your variables have `/` in them? Try changing the delimiters. Use `#` or `@` instead of `/`.

Comment: Do you mean, I should use `sed -i "s#$name#$category#g" ./animals.txt`?

Comment: Yea! If this doesn't work you might have to show in exactly on which text it happens so that I can debug it more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

Use double-quotes so the shell will interpolate your variables:

```
sed -i "s/$name/$category/g" ./animals.txt
```

Comment: This returns the error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 73: unknown option to `s'".

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/$name/$category/g" ./animals.txt
```

Comment: Note that this only works for simple strings. For example, to replace anything which contains a literal `*`, `.`, `/` or other special characters you'll need a more complicated solution.