# Replace string variable with string variable using Sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file called **ethernet** containing multiple lines. I have saved one of these lines as a variable called **old_line**. The contents of this variable looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="2r:11:89:89:9g:ah", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

I have created a second variable called **new_line** that is similar to **old_line** but with some modifications in the text.

I want to substitute the contents of **old_line** with the contents of **new_line** using sed. So far I have the following, but it doesn't work:

```
sed -i "s/${old_line}/${new_line}/g" ethernet
```

Comment: Try without the {} around variables ? Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938571/find-and-replace-variables-containing-non-escaped-characters-with-sed

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to escape your `oldline` so that it contains no regex special characters, luckily this can be done with sed.

```
old_line=$(echo "${old_line}" | sed -e 's/[]$.*[\^]/\\&/g' )
sed -i -e "s/${old_line}/${new_line}/g" ethernet
```

Comment: Yes, that totally did the trick! I am very grateful PatJ!!

Comment: For a more general case, "/" should be escaped too as long as "\" and "&" in the new_line variable.

Answer (score 5):

Since `${old_line}` contains many regex special metacharacters like `*`, `?` etc therefore your `sed` is failing.

Use this `awk` command instead that uses **no regex**:

```
awk -v old="$old_line" -v new="$new_line" 'p=index($0, old) {
      print substr($0, 1, p-1) new substr($0, p+length(old)) }' ethernet
```

Comment: Thanks, I copied the script but it only echoes the variable contents of the new variable in my terminal. It doesn't modify the file **ethernet**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not "wrong" per se, it's just that plain-jane Awk does not support inline editing.  If you have Gawk, try adding an `--inline` option. If not, store in a temp file and move it on top of the original.

Comment: Ok, in case I use gawk, what should the command look like?

If gawk doesn't work, I need to replace the old line, is there a way to delete the line?

Comment: Same command will work on gawk also (in fact I have also tested it on gawk)

Comment: @tripleee: I think you meant in-_place_ editing and `-i inplace`, available in Gawk v4.1+

Comment: Oh, quite so, sorry for the confusion.