# Yet another example of sed needing some escape foo

Tags: sed, makefile

I'm trying to use `sed` to edit a file within a makefile.  When I edit a date, in the format xxxx-yy-zz it works fine.  When I try to edit a version number with a format of x.y.z, it fails. I'm pretty certain this is because I need to escape the `.` in the version for the grep part of `sed`.  I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563120/633251) but it doesn't work, and I'm not good enough at this to figure it out (similar advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705678/633251)).  I can't give a working example due to use of external files, but here is the basic idea:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash # bash is needed for manipulation of version number
PKG_NAME=FuncMap
TODAY=$(shell date +%Y-%m-%d)
PKG_VERSION := $(shell grep -i '^version' $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
PKG_DATE := $(shell grep -i '^date' $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION | cut -d ':' -f2)

## Increment the z in of x.y.z

XYZ=$(subst ., , $(PKG_VERSION))
X=$(word 1, $(XYZ))
Y=$(word 2, $(XYZ))
Z=$(word 3, $(XYZ))
Z2=$$(($(Z)+1))
NEW_VERSION=$(addsuffix $(addprefix .,$(Z2)), $(addsuffix $(addprefix ., $(Y)), $(X)))
OLD_VERSION=$(echo "$(PKG_VERSION)" | sed -e 's/[]$.*[\^]/\\&/g' )

all: info update

info:
    @echo "Package: " $(PKG_NAME)
    @echo "Current/Pending version numbers: " $(PKG_VERSION) $(NEW_VERSION)
    @echo "Old date: " $(PKG_DATE)
    @echo "Today: " $(TODAY)
    @echo "OLD_VERSION: " $(OLD_VERSION)

update: $(shell find $(PKG_NAME) -name "DESCRIPTION")
    @echo "Editing DESCRIPTION to increment version"
    $(shell sed 's/$(OLD_VERSION)/$(NEW_VERSION)/' $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION > $(PKG_NAME)/TEST)
    @echo "Editing DESCRIPTION to update the date"
    $(shell sed 's/$(PKG_DATE)/$(TODAY)/' $(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION > $(PKG_NAME)/TEST)
```

And this gives as output:

```
Package:  FuncMap
Current/Pending version numbers:  1.0.1000 1.0.1001
Current date:  2000-07-99
Today:  2015-07-11
OLD_VERSION: 
sed: first RE may not be empty
Editing DESCRIPTION to increment version
Editing DESCRIPTION to update the date
```

Obviously the `sed` on the version number is not working (the date is handled fine, and current/pending versions are correct, and the date is properly changed in the external file).  Besides this particular problem, I'm sure a lot of this code is suboptimal - don't laugh! I don't know `make` nor shell scripting very well...

Comment: `OLD_VERSION` should be `PKG_VERSION` but in a form (escaping the `.` ?) that will work in the `sed` in rule `update`.  Using `PKG_VERSION` in the `sed` line doesn't work correctly either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Comment: @Ed Morton: I don't think the usecase described by OP actually requires escaping anything. The goal is to replace `1.0.1000` with `1.0.1001` using `sed` in the Makefile `update` target. So, this should work: `sed "s/$(PKG_VERSION)/$(NEW_VERSION)/" "$(PKG_NAME)/DESCRIPTION" > "$(PKG_NAME)/TEST"`

Comment: @EugeniuRosca that could fail since the `.` will be treated as any character so if he happens to have something like `12031000` in his file it will be replaced with `1.0.1001`. He also should be using word boundaries.

Comment: @EdMorton So where does this stand?  I *do* need to escape things?

Comment: @BryanHanson yes, you do, and you need to anchor the expression.

Comment: Can you post an answer I can study?  Or something in the comments?  Thank you.

Comment: My first comment was a reference to another answer - study that and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, to simplify things I wouldn't do this inside a makefile, I'd create a shell script and have it called from the makefile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83083/discussion-between-bryan-hanson-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 0):

`OLD_VERSION` is empty, because you omitted the makefile `shell` function:

```
OLD_VERSION=$(shell echo "$(PKG_VERSION)" | sed -e 's/[]$.*[\^]/\\&/g' )
```

Comment: Ah, sillyness on my part (the missing shell). Thanks for the explanation in your answer, very helpful.